# libfixmath's atan2 seems to produce invalid results - any ideas, suggestions or alternatives?

Tags: c++, trigonometry, fixed-point

I want to do fixed point math in C++, so I looked for a suitable library. [`libfixmath`](https://code.google.com/p/libfixmath/) has been suggested here a couple of times, but I have difficulties with the `atan2` function it provides. My test code calculates sine and cosine of an angle and then recalculates that angle using `atan2`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <fix16.h>
#include <fix16.hpp>

int main()
{
  unsigned int n = 1000;
  std::ofstream atan2File("atan2.dat");
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
  {
    double d = M_PI/2.*i/n;
    double s = sin(d);
    double c = cos(d);
    double a = atan2(s,c);
    Fix16 df(d);
    Fix16 sf(df.sin());
    Fix16 cf(df.cos());
    Fix16 af(sf.atan2(cf));
    atan2File << d
              << " " << a
              << " " << (double)af
              << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the plotted result:
[image]

It was generated with `gnuplot` using

```
plot "atan2.dat" u 1:2 w l title 'double', "atan2.dat" u 1:3 w l title 'Fix16'
```

Some values near zero and pi/2 are reasonable, but a lot are not. The code seems to use [this algorithm](http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/tricks/fixed-point-atan2-with-self-normalization) for calculating `atan2`, but I couldn't spot where it might fail in the way shown above.

- Does anyone know of a possible bug in the `libfixmath` code?
- Is there an alternative library that provides trigonometric functions for fixed point values? I need sine, cosine, tangent and their inverse.

I could, of course, try to add the missing functions to other suggested fixed point libraries, but I don't have any experience in writing code for fixed point types.

gcc -v: `gcc version 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012] (SUSE Linux)`

I need fixed point because I want to do these calculations on a Cortex-M4 (no FPU). Actually I already had `libfixmath` in my Cortex-M4 code, but it has shown errors like those described above. OTOH, it was about 10 times as fast as the `float` version. I'd like to add more or less correct results to that speed.

Comment: Not reproducible for me with gcc-4.4.3 or clang-3.5 with gcc's stdlib.

Comment: Just to clarify *not reproducible*: I see a mostly smooth deviation of libfixmath's `atan2` as a function `phi` which is about 20% above the stdlib version at the very lowest `phi`. That deviation drops below 1% above `phi=0.4`.

Comment: hm....I'll try to produce a file using the Cortex-M4 code later and see how that actually looks. How are those 20% defined?

Comment: Relative to the stdlib version, `(fixed-stdlib)/stdlib`. Note that that 20% is a small absolute number.

Comment: So in terms of the above you calculated `((double)af-a)/a`? To me it's kinda scary that this behavior couldn't be reproduced by you. Could any compiler flags have caused this?

Comment: Yes, that's what I calculated. I used the standard C(XX)FLAGS in `libfixmath/Makefile`, both to build the archive and the test case.

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 and the compiler is executed with `gcc -Wextra -Wall -DFIXMATH_NO_CACHE -O2`, so the only difference compared to the makefile is no caching (can't do that on my actual target due to limited RAM).

Comment: Did you ever come right with this? I've been planning to use libfixmath for a while, across different platforms. Don't need things like this biting me!